# Using tensorflow_model_server with ssl configuration

Tags: tensorflow, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tensorflow-serving

I have been having trouble configuring tensorflow to use ssl certificates.  In run the experiments in my local machine.  The `tensorflow` environment I am using is as specified in `tensorflow/serving:1.14.0-gpu` Dockerfile.

When calling the command:

```
tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 --model_config_file=<path_here> --ssl_config_file=tf_ssl.pb
```

The model loads well, but I get the following error:

```
E1205 16:16:11.240133400       7 ssl_transport_security.cc:675] Invalid cert chain file.
E1205 16:16:11.240876900       7 ssl_security_connector.cc:276] Handshaker factory creation failed with TSI_INVALID_ARGUMENT.
E1205 16:16:11.240950800       7 server_secure_chttp2.cc:81] {"created":"@1575562571.240923200","description":"Unable to create secure server with credentials of type Ssl.","file":"external/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/secure/server_secure_chttp2.cc","file_line":63}
```

The contents of the `tf_ssl.pb` file are as follows:

```
server_key: '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEArq6bpXNgZt5yBoESjIuIcK9gyW+Ur5X4NJX7an93HqByhItCORLn/vHC9ACpfJARFaAPE8f0YLt8tZi+2OJ0PfQ9OQO6qQpwCgHkC2GrOCjGe9FqtdjZnBj6N19wXvXvcyNYJxVdbTUvPR10lKbCk8MaOs0ZU2KLIC3qsSrUBjsRAZXQFIMzPOVZ2UH4j1r2T66ufF0sGeW6mtDOSNZxZfGZ5/Xos1UAt7A8wDKDagRo1HJA1lPAWM9lCSVsmkeFnouu3mXyy8hNDfm3ge2mwReRXKK/4g2qyiAfaU7gopRA5uNgXLvP690cWT25xeQ6+vZLLnmkCIWzZLoqqVpClxhFfVuyxQo0LuJwMTADqUSi3e0qGCW1SmHQqOQpnGlK18JqKrqgIxk03sKaHvcrnqTGaG0yZAjypZ49Ajv23KvsoZd3zb7D904vg/Lo2zXks1KyPHNqx5e3zsmSi310WQLgNCPSuFKNKNknpkmEUn+Ev/DDMO7Xj203ta8YuGVWElmne6IpCGB3JI/Mbeu4EXQpS173mTexgSW4I5rz0/dX9Z6NapjX39v2YZwD2MsVIgdFL5vabM0BQ0AomNvM9d3PrGek0bnKR8/3ak6k07cL56N8yokow4x0HsIQlxZgVmKAJZDVZGZeowOVFqoNBrRCSg2OWLANdS3qttd88SUCAwEAAQKCAgEAiueKGWy/0c09evKUX3JtUr4DButVnrJwptBFFpC5ln8b0U4zoNLp7I8u6XzFSan+C+Y1VxN/vpQYPQdza1/X85QOQxI2EkmcgjiysGJAFu5Ftxv18Ri5IimyfunDn5+Ng08twBZ7LmZGZCDSHYrl2z4f03ZYlzgbTcF1iOB3rWS2xz3sMwOJcPkoE10kXEqG5yIO2hH1CbrmQkmcX8s2bUxLiGrBWilT4r2f8W25lkpfWeBosoXyxCxXOYiq7ZvGIycMLQmAoo9qxpw2Unk6Sv2Et9crIoSftQ8KK2Fvu5iMa42PiO5IDlTLQCOXYEd2py3G5vQPfj9jQcvQNM7zd4WSCHal1nrVcDegMmX3ZIF1sBN4S5ZMDHsWmCv4cdvj+Si0HWzVLrly5DDet2sMx31uF4tjKkPMVZlV8oxGad0d7P36GYoAkAooNwWdeF38k5atdCJw2u1aFFceI8ZC3gv6zXIW1/u7Apdfpk7k7b0KMW4SHz2WDJcsadP+JdkXSO8q7Q+4yToFrtFUswr2vaAzps1N7xko5N9hYB42ohwK5XoNPU7mezNhkS8u0Nx/0LsCaOdQwTUaUsfQQC+eYsAY5xHud/NPlFv0Jin44oKJOKXxNUtfGzu4mC+nwqGevqKzonGFQBkXkvi/fwDrNYa2k0wOFv8uHb5umSXYC4ECggEBAOT3vYwGVkef65tyDpXfb9E1IwdYYGkk0yWh0wfEX7jr6qYc8/WTHe41LjesI5w06Fo+Rkj2v/pE9dRzvCmxVu0MsoXAun0goS7laDCb6+H7B4QxSRS2jh21HQJbTkYx8CJXkKs2Nv3jfP9Yhgjc1oaEGl3Bso/k2/HdRZeZQIa+GvWUV25la3vMn1fFybTG6gSxjVBNACZB1uWmWTtqiCXauT4/Tg8IljsriWjATtE42gJ7q3MZJOr2Qm52dFhuqPdAoNQYvgHzMqyyz+D45EYAL7N5rrgBrvEm3WjuO2ZTJFhDqgU5H1bujdBONJHYMl/pyKhSvYElwCp1+XyLD7ECggEBAMNOJuNDKotihoMCXpShg/JfHQKunnb6da/h1W0FRWRUQGP3RwPWRRBs0r5MTnuIBnqG7hLZiLDozemAl38nLvAHQF5Nbvp/W8SRV0b/ysXnNQzlDLfMb3tDXJA8IJ1LcmIWNs53nQiG5oB7hSOMMr15u5wL804NnqNJECH9oHz7Ahj3XbjeZmHd1ImuQeQ6yWE3PSdVF6IdDzxz69Z9M1J9xMvP93CcUSeIfwI6qsilSXL0bjtk26phBzHTHTHILa95TrQv0xA8CrxcynXZsi2Z4nt0H/1XgMgLPn9wzmmrywCMQLrCoH8OkDj5DcXTb5GP+aVIUuq8iH7XeCN/qbUCggEBAJb7IbsGprgeJM9gu2tqZaJPZqS+SvyqMq068xvJCtG2hwk4SEoj03WzDaHaWbT0Uk7Hh7MvOlI+TNfl5Sqc7NPtLn7yIkbGUGLLFRQQjM97p24szaLh6f5+4f0e1hOFdHJAyX2Mh2CNNGxwJBoN/UvAKl6ujh9CayImpXActybijoZnZeu+5sxAlsXa/3G8RK4JokRUMggIHDtcoLSEP/iuLL52IfPZ1q53u+kd/hsKYP+IKvr/lo91CUMryvZRKgu4SxTwp8JDaqPkWR1hIa1jDBFN6L8fJQuRdChwBy0nH+0v2RoOm7LIJS05lIKjTDxgvVb5EErr6LZXCsdsL1ECggEATwys1MN0zuHcC97DpWkSXOF+fn1rCkEprTy9A9lkUs1/GncVuUnavmEtk3STN5DA/orqhZqipugzn9U6fG7Boslslj7FMoKmBBPHvab+zcddQ5DZ6vLGFKAZMRAFK2VEMMtI95yWZMMlPM/B/bdbOjGxa+GyYt9EXFbQPtHHSY7XNH+64X6y9d2xjuCHLvdUVxLin67jV+xnJFLPHAuk4DijlNLiFiRO/K9UqPRR99BewDaK/2M9PeLz5IjMgj/BrgptfqT0ytdiiQcNs1GfurFUaB+Cayolp9JVQ4PHKCIuklQyRuVLzOF6InU7y9xehg4+P1XcqcIRhTV1HPkpGQKCAQEAt24Uhm66akL9Ak/ib7DuJWl9iDRw911BYqBVNbMtcW0iZMasHtEUk+eM8g9CVfKwVHlHP/fNBL+bkPMcceJ3HYjDRgXZLjbt+16/EG3+N1xd2kPZhRufulVZ2I73PjLFfUNlKmLUXaYR0sNfOP1bmvPCupwnuM699nDQEZOJXJEPgbWvQzfUSz5K8f90eH70bB72Sl7qxSX8CZYI5ATTBUY5MacLkvpnLrs1Xvup9vFyoJ3OnDBP9OAe5e/hH3e7FYT2vV40r4KQqGmPF3MNj4eMmfTUaqcN7eNteoNmJ9YrlBNu486NFmKWkbtGPgNkKAIOv9x95r8X3R/xFObuvQ==-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
server_cert: '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----'
custom_ca: '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----'
client_verify: false
```

And those keys were created with the following script:

```
echo Generate CA key:
openssl genrsa -passout pass:1111 -des3 -out ca.key 4096

echo Generate CA certificate:
openssl req -passin pass:1111 -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj  "/C=US/ST=CA/L=Cupertino/O=YourCompany/OU=YourApp/CN=MyRootCA"

echo Generate server key:
openssl genrsa -passout pass:1111 -des3 -out server.key 4096

echo Generate server signing request:
openssl req -passin pass:1111 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj  "/C=US/ST=CA/L=Cupertino/O=YourCompany/OU=YourApp/CN=localhost"

echo Self-sign server certificate:
openssl x509 -req -passin pass:1111 -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt

echo Remove passphrase from server key:
openssl rsa -passin pass:1111 -in server.key -out server.key
```

I really would like to know if the problem consists in the way that I have been creating the certificates, or if it is due to an incorrect format of the `tf_ssl.pb` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to concatenate certs/keys lines with `\n` in `tf_ssl.pb`, e.g.:

```
server_cert: '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n< CERT >\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----'
```